Not able to generate Dynamic URL and perform search
I am new to HTMX. I have a Spring Data Rest as per below:
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "softwares", path = "softwares")
public interface AppSoftwareRepository extends JpaRepository<AppSoftware, Long> {

    @RestResource(path = "softwarenameContaining", rel = "softwarenameContaining")
    Page<AppSoftware> findBySoftwarenameContainingIgnoreCase(@Param("softwarename") String softwarename, Pageable p);
    

I am able to get the list of softwares and implement "load more" using this end point:
/softwares

at my list html page which is at:
http://localhost:8080/list

No issues till this point.
Now, I am trying to follow a tutorial to create a dynamic search where the search box input should be the input for my REST URI -
http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=AcrobatReater
The enpoint works perfectly fine in browser and gives me 1 result JSON back.
But on the page, no matter how hard I try I can not get the expected result, it always shows 0 results. Also I am not sure how to debug HTMX.
What I am missing or might be doing wrong? Any clue/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Can you provide more details please? Does the htmx make an actual request to the backend, do you get any errors in the web console etc? To debug it, maybe try to trip down all the custom js first and start from the most basic example, then monitor when things break when adding back the custom code.

No errors whatsoever. That is the surprising part. The entire code and project is here: https://github.com/ajkr195/SoftwareManager

Its resolved. Had a typo. Now its working fine.
